# Representing a ratio-based integral value

Tags: c++, math, c++20

Is there a way to model a ratio-based numerical value so that it goes through the same conversion process as the chrono types? For example, imagine `std::rate` is what I want; then if I have the following API

```
void foo(std::rate<std::mega, std::milli> byteRate);
```

Where `byteRate` represents MB/ms. Now, if I call it with a `std::rate<std::mega, std::ratio<1>>` indicating MB/s, the right arithmetic conversion happens.

Is there anything in the standard library for this? `std::ratio` and `std::ratio_divide` don't fit, because they don't allow representing values at runtime. If there's a better pattern for this, that would be nice as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean `std::chrono::duration`?

Comment: [`boost::units`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/doc/html/boost_units.html) was written for that purpose. And there are also [boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/doc/html/ratio/reference.html)::[ratio](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/doc/html/ratio/users_guide.html) and [boost::rational](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/libs/rational/rational.html)

Comment: @phuclv Hmmm, boost::units seems applicable, but it seems to be fairly complex, and it's hard for me to figure out how to get exactly what I want. Do you kno whow I can represent my hypothetical `rate` class with boost::units?

Comment: @康桓瑋 That's interesting.. I guess I could just either use that out of the box, or with a wrapper. Duration does provide a customizable ratio<> that can be updated, with say `std::ratio<1000000/1>` to show MB/s